# I can not install ClamAV to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, dependencies, antivirus, clamav

I'm trying install ClamAV antivirus to my Ubuntu desktop machine, but I got some errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clamav clamav-deamon -y
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clamav : Depends: clamav-freshclam (>= 0.103.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed or
                   clamav-data
          Depends: libclamav9 (>= 0.103.2) but it is not going to be installed
 clamav-daemon : Depends: clamav-freshclam (>= 0.103.2+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed or
                          clamav-data
                 Depends: libclamav9 (>= 0.103.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: clamdscan but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

- Machine: Nvidia jetson TX2 ARM architecture
- OS: Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS

Comment: `you have requested an impossible situation` and `you have held broken packages` suggest that you have unwisely installed non-Ubuntu or wrong-version packages that are incompatible with your 18.04 system. You fix the problem by uninstalling those non-Ubuntu or wrong-version packages, and by disabling/deleting their source.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `apt policy X`where X is all the packages listed in your error output. One command per package; please continue to post text, not pictures.